# Cannot access innerHTML of span tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this piece of code:

```
var size = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('checked').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```

For some reason every time I run it I get this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object NodeList] has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Even though all my other functions with `getElementsByTagName()` work fine. What could be the reason for this error?

Thanks

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` also returns a set of elements, not a single element.

Comment: The error says it all...

Comment: if you want to match all span tags you need to iterate through the array of nodes you got returned by `.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a set of elements (i.e. `NodeList`), not a single element:

```
iframe
    .contentWindow
    .document
    .getElementsByClassName('checked')[0]  // <--- [0] (or whatever index)
    .getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
    .innerHTML;
```

Besides you can replace it with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector):

```
iframe
    .contentWindow
    .document
    .querySelector(".checked span")
    .innerHTML;
```

Comment: `querySelector` is perfect for this. warning: it does not work in IE7

Comment: @Eru as well as `getElementsByClassName`, and since the OP uses it, I decided to suggest `querySelector`.